# MySQL selecting from multiple tables into a single table

Tags: mysql, database, insert

I have 3 tables.

Table A:
TA_ID
TA_NAME

Table B:
TB_ID
TB_NAME
TA_ID

TABLE C:
TC_ID
TC_NAME
TA_ID
TB_ID

I want to insert a name into Table C while getting the id from table A and id from table B, check that these TA_ID and TB_ID match and then insert. How would I do this, could I get a link to a good example?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is an INSERT ... SELECT statement. There are plenty of examples on the internet, and the first place to start would be: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Thanks, thats all I wanted was what type of query I should use. And after 2 negative marks and an obvious remark from someone else, You actually give a bit of advice, cheers.